# How to set up labels on both halves of semi-doughnut chart?

Tags: d3.js

I am making a half circle doughnut chart, that currently looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rcxp0udt/

You can notice that all of the labels are on the right side of the chart. How ever, I would like to make them look something like this: http://prntscr.com/d4p8qb - so that labels of first half of the semi-circle are on one side, and other half is on the other side. Here is the part of the code that is responsible for that:

```
 polyline.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("points", function(d){
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
            pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
        };
    });
```

However, every solution I tried so far in my tests to achieve this has ended up failing. If you have any idea how to achieve this effect, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `midAngle(d2) < Math.PI`, use `midAngle(d2) > 0`:

[image: screenshot of updated pie chart]

Make this change where add the text and draw the text polylines (lines 165, 175, and 202).